# jquery.ajax - how to remove http headers from .net web service response

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, http-headers

The problem I am having with JQuery seems simple, but I have been googling for answer for a while now, and still can not figure it out.

I have a .net web project with google charts. I am using JQuery ajax to populate the charts. I have a web service .asmx page to service ajax calls.

```js
var raw_data = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax_WebService.asmx/Hello",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
            }).responseText;
```

I have a very simple web method in my web service:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Function Hello() As String
    Return "hello"
End Function
```

All I want to get in the raw_data variable is hello.
Instead I get hello wrapped in the http headers like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://my_web_site.com/">hello</string>
```

I do know how to use a regular aspx web form to service the calls. But I am trying to use a web service.
Also, I can not disable the http headers on the iis level.

My question is - can I make it work with web service either by telling it not to send headers, or by filtering them out at the end with jquery? If yes - could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Response.Write rather than just returning the string.

Response.Write returns the formatted string.